# Three.js Error creating WebGL context

Tags: three.js, webgl, webgl-extensions

Friends, I need your help, the following code in three.js, all return null in this line:

_context || _canvas.getContext( 'webgl', attributes ) || _canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl', attributes );

---

```
function initGL() {

    try {

        var attributes = {
            alpha: _alpha,
            depth: _depth,
            stencil: _stencil,
            antialias: _antialias,
            premultipliedAlpha: _premultipliedAlpha,
            preserveDrawingBuffer: _preserveDrawingBuffer
        };

        _gl = _context || _canvas.getContext( 'webgl', attributes ) || _canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl', attributes );

        if ( _gl === null ) {

            throw 'Error creating WebGL context.';

        }

    } catch ( error ) {

        console.error( error );

    }

    _glExtensionTextureFloat = _gl.getExtension( 'OES_texture_float' );
```

the attributes value:

[image]

this is canvas:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

~Rosone

Comment: Shouldn't you mention which browser and OS you're using? Is it one of the ones supported? Does it support WebGL?

Comment: win2008 server, chrome, threejs example can work. I'm reviewing the code. actually just:this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
            this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, this.canvas.width / this.canvas.height, 0.1, 1000);
            this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: this.canvas, antialias: true });

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason: It's because another context `(canvas.getContext('2d') )` already occupied this same canvas.

Comment: IMHO, this can happen simply by creating new `<canvas>` instances in different pages in a single-page app. Do your best to "destroy" the previous `<canvas>` element and instances related libraries (e.g. a 3d engine).